# For login, request provides user details in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a Django todo app by using the Django rest framework where I ran into this problem.

I am authenticating the user via the rest framework so that I am able to get an authentication token, for the user. My views.py...

```
def login(request):
    print("\n\n", request, "\n\n")
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user =  authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(user)
            response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/", data={"username":username, "password":password})
            token =  json.loads(response.text).get("token")
            request.session["token"] = f"Token {token}"
            request.session.modified = True

            # r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", headers={"Authorization":request.session["token"]})
            return redirect("home")
            

        else:
            return render(request, "todo/login.html", {"message":"Your entered credentials are wrong"})

    else:
        return render(request, "todo/login.html")
```

In which I have figured that when my user input is **invalid**, the `request` parameter carries the value `<WSGIRequest: POST '/login'>`. But when the user input is valid the `request`  parameter carries my user details (the value `najaaz` - my username). This output was figured out using the print statement in line 2.

Since it carries my user details I get the following error `'User' object has no attribute 'method'`, since the line `if request.method == "POST":` would be invalid then.

This is something new for me, and I am a bit unsure of how to get it done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
'User' object has no attribute 'method'
```

usually happens because django thinks that you are overriding its **login** method, try naming your view something else ,

```
def log_in_view(request):
  print("\n\n", request, "\n\n")
  if request.method == "POST":
    ...
```